# How to set battery charging thresholds on T420s

Tags: 13.04, laptop, battery, thinkpad, tp-smapi

**I have a ThinkPad T420s and would like to expand the battery service life (not maximize time the laptop can run off a battery)**

I have `tp-smapi-dkms` and `sysfsutils` installed, and when I run:

```
$ ll /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Sep 12 08:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    0 Sep 12 07:59 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 barcoding
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:26 charging_max_current
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:26 charging_max_voltage

...

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 power_avg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 power_now
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 remaining_capacity
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 remaining_charging_time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 remaining_percent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:26 remaining_percent_error
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 remaining_running_time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:26 remaining_running_time_now
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 serial
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:17 start_charge_thresh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 state
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:00 stop_charge_thresh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 temperature
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:15 voltage
```

So there should be `start_charge_thresh` and `stop_charge_thresh` available, I can set when the battery stops charging with:

```
$ echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh
80
$ echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh
80
```

**But setting when it should start charging fails:**

```
$ echo 40 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh 
40
$ cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh 
cat: /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh: No such device or address
```

How is this possible? I am running out of time.. **when I plug in the adapter it still isn't charging!**

Answer (score 4):

please take the following steps and remember backup your configuration before you do anything:

```
sudo modprobe tp_smapi
lsmod | grep smapi
sudo echo "tp_smapi" >> /etc/modules
sudo echo "devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh = 40" >> /etc/sysfs.conf
sudo echo "devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh = 80" >> /etc/sysfs.conf
sudo service sysfsutils start
```

reboot your device and check it out!

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but could you elaborate your answer a little? I have the same problem as the OP, but I don't understand at all what these changes are supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: This won't work, obviously. Doesn't matter if you set it from console or in some config file when the threshold doesn't work at all… See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, T420 and some other Thinkpads have the `start_charge_thresh` broken/crippled somehow (https://github.com/evgeni/tp_smapi/issues/3).

I solved it by using `tpacpi-bat` instead of the `tp_smapi` module: https://github.com/teleshoes/tpacpi-bat